# Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 54

Tags: selenium, firefox

I am trying to run my Selenium tests using Selenium 2.53 and Firefox 54 , it does not work . Has anyone else faced the same problem and have any solutions to it?

Comment: Have you tried updating Selenium?

Comment: what is the err message?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 54 is too new for Selenium 2.53, latest Firefox versions works only with latest Selenium version.
You can [download](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0/) and install Firefox 46 - that should work fine with Selenium 2.53. Make sure to disable auto updates in Firefox.
Or you can update your selenium to latest [3.4.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.4.0).

Comment: That works but did not want to restrict the firefox version , as that gets autoupated. Maybe for now , we'd have just restrict the auto update on firefox. Thank you